# Append Query String to GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, blazor

I'm trying to get shared driveItems using Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient (v2.13.3). Official doc [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#response) says:

> ...To include items shared from external tenants, append `?allowexternal=true` to a GET request.

I would like to append this query string in the following command:
`var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].SharedWithMe.GetAsync();`

I've tried to [provide custom query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#provide-custom-query-parameters):

`var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].SharedWithMe.GetAsync(requestConfiguration => {`      requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.AllowExternal = true });`but`AllowExternal` isn't recognized by compiler.

Older versions of GraphClient allowed for `await graphClient...Request()`, but this was removed in v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the query parameter allowExternal is missing.

As a workaround, you need to modify the URL template of `SharedWithMeRequestBuilder`

```
var requestInfo = graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"]
    .SharedWithMe
    .ToGetRequestInformation();
requestInfo.QueryParameters["allowExternal"] = new string[] { "true" };
var index = requestInfo.UrlTemplate.Length;
requestInfo.UrlTemplate = requestInfo.UrlTemplate.Insert(index - 1, ",allowExternal");
var result = await new SharedWithMeRequestBuilder(requestInfo.URI.OriginalString, graphClient.RequestAdapter).GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Graph SDK (which the Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient builds upon) doesn't provide a built-in way to add custom query parameters directly to specific endpoint calls, especially if they're not directly exposed as properties in the request configuration object.

However, there's a workaround you can use to achieve your goal:

**Using HTTP Request Features**: You can use the .GetHttpRequestMessage() method to get the underlying HttpRequestMessage and then manually modify it to include the desired query parameter.
Here's how you can do it:

```
// Create the request
var request = graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].SharedWithMe
                    .CreateRequest()
                    .GetHttpRequestMessage();

// Append the query parameter manually
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query["allowexternal"] = "true";  // Add the custom parameter
uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;

// Send the modified request
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);

// Handle the response
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my graphClient does not have a `…SharedWithMe.CreateRequest()` method, and to make things even worse, `graphClient.HttpProvider` doesn’t exist also (I can see it exists in official docs on the web).Maybe I could get around first obstacle (CreateRequest), since there is `ToGetRequestInformation()`, which returns `{Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.RequestInformation}`, but this object doesn't contain any authentication headers. For the second part, I simply can not find any method to send a »raw« HTTP request (by »raw« I mean URL).

Comment: I’m beginning to wonder that maybe I have some dependencies mixed up. This might be the case, because with so many different Microsoft.Graph packages and versions,  I found it very confusing to find the right ones. Currently I have installed (remember it’s a Blazor Server app):
`Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient`, both latest (v2.13.3). Adding Microsoft.Graph (v5.24.0) and Microsoft.Graph.Core (v3.0.10) didn’t help either.

Any idea how to proceed next?